# How to get the source code with proper indentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do a drag and drop builder. There are two section, on one there will be some buttons, and the other section will be the preview section.

I have append the HTML parts on a `table` that has class `.container` on that `.preview-section`. Now i want to get the source code. I have used the below code to get the source code but the things are getting very messy.

I want the code to be formatted in a proper way. For example check the link given below. Drag a section and check the source code. I want to have the source code as you'll get on the ck-editor builder after dragging an element.
https://nazifa22.github.io/Builder---CK-Editor-/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// This is how i append the code on .main-container
$(".container-btn").click(function(){
  $.get('./parts/main-container.html', function(data) {
     $('.preview-section').append(data);
  });
});

$(".source-btn").click(function(){
   $(".preview-section").text($(".preview-section").html());
});
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-around">
    <!-- Buttons -->
    <div class="col-lg-4 button-section">

    </div>
    <!-- Appending on this section-->
    <div class="col-lg-7 preview-section">

    </div>
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CK-Editor works hard to make it works.

Comment: I just want the source code to be exactly the same as it is on ck editor.